# Property Utils type conversion Boolean to String Java 1.8 expecting type conversion error

Tags: java, type-conversion, apache-commons-beanutils

I'm migrating some project from Java 1.6 -> 1.8 and problem is with 
Apache Commons library (migrating some old version -> commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar).

I have this Foo class that extends HasMap, let's say that it loads some flags ( i left out only one in the real example there are more than 20 attributes)

```
public class Foo extends HashMap<String, Object> {
    public String getSomeFlag(){
        return super.get("someFlag");
    }
    public void setSomeFlag(String SomeFlag){
        super.put("someFlag", SomeFlag);
    }
    public void setSomeFlag(boolean SomeFlag){
        if(SomeFlag)
            super.put("someFlag", "Y");
        else
            super.put("someFlag", "N");
    }
}
```

The older version of commons library didn't allow type conversion ( Boolean to String) but now apparently this is not enforced.

```
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setSomeFlag("N");

    System.out.println("FooFlag value: " + foo.getSomeFlag());

    Boolean someFlagBoolean = new Boolean(true);

    try {
        PropertyUtils.setProperty(foo, "someFlag", someFlagBoolean); //i expect error here but it passes this line
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("FooString value: " + foo.getSomeFlag());
```

In the old version of commons library exception was thrown on this line, and that was fine, we handled it( code omitted for simplicity).

```
 PropertyUtils.setProperty(foo, "someFlag", someFlagBoolean );
```

The output looks like this:

```
FooFlag  value: N
FooString value: true
```

Is there a way to enforce type checking when doing PropertyUtils.setProperty

expecting this error

```
9.04.2018. 16:22:34 org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean invokeMethod
SEVERE: Method invocation failed.
Throwable occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1773)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1759)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1641)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1677)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.setProperty(PropertyUtils.java:559)
    at hr.etna.framework.common.object.ObjectMapperHelper.setAttribute(ObjectMapperHelper.java:69)
```

Comment: *Is there a way to enforce type checking when doing PropertyUtils.setProperty* - what do you actually want to happen in case of argument type mismatch?

Comment: I expect exception to be thrown, that was the behevior in old version of the library

Comment: I found this in API documentation does it mean that i need to extend if I want same behavior https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean.html#setPropertyOfMapBean-java.util.Map-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-

Comment: I think your problem is that your `Foo` effectively implements `Map`. So `PropertyUtilsBean` sees it as a "map bean" and simply calls `bean.put(propertyName, value)` bypassing your setter.

Comment: Does `Foo` really need to extend `HashMap`? Can't you just wrap it? I think this would be the easiest solution.

Comment: Otherwise - yes, `PropertyUtilsBean` seem to be implemented with extension in mind. You can subclass it and change the behaviour.

Comment: I agree extending HashMap is bad practice but this is a legacy code and part of the large framework, I simplified it a lot. I wanted to keep it simple and change as less as possible. Now I need to find out how to make this extended class :)